# ng-click in the inner template of the directive is not providing the functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ng-click` is not providing alert. When the inner template of the directive is clicked alert box is not shown.

The fiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NNDhX/

Comment: I don't even look at questions where they didn't bother to edit down to something posted inline in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your directive has its own **isolated scope**. So function 'hi' should be inside directive's scope. If you want to pass your controller's function you should do binding, like `scope: { ..., hi: '&' }` and then `<you-directive hi='hi' ..>`. Here is a link to documentation about this: [Understanding Transclusion and Scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

So just adding it in linking function is enough:

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.hi = function() { alert("hi"); }
```

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBAh/

Comment: Thanks for your solution Valentyn Shybanov   But I want to call the hi() function in the controller... Please update this fiddle

Comment: I mentioned the way how to call hi from the controller: update scope property of directive and bind to your controller function. Fiddle with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBAh/1/ 

Do not forget: directive scope is isolated, so you can or pass something to this scope using binding or use transclusion - transcluded scopes are siblings and are not isolated.

Comment: @ValentynShybanov You should put that fiddle in the answer to save future readers some time. :)  And Angular should make it easier than typing unintuitive stuff like `scope: { func: '&' }`!

Comment: Can the function be inside controller of the directive or should be exactly in link function.

Comment: No, there is no difference where you define function on the scope.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is the best way but you can use $parent in directive to access parent scope.

```
<a ng-click="$parent.hi();">parent</a>
```

Here is link to full fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EKDse/

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of isolate scopes is exactly to avoid 'sharing' things between parent<->child scopes, somehow protecting them from being exposed and (unintentionally) changed by other directives/controllers.

**If you really want to avoid the isolate scope and share the parent's scope**, try this:

Start by removing the directive's scope definition (commented below):

```
transclude: true,
/*scope: { title:'@zippyTitle' },*/
```

Then place the attributes (`attrs`) from the directive element on the directives' scope:

```
scope.attrs = attrs;
```

Note: By doing this the `attrs` property will also be available on the parent (Ctrl3) scope.

And finally define the title based on the `scope.attrs`

```
  template: '<div>' +
              '<div class="title">{{attrs.zippyTitle}}</div>' +
              '<div class="body" ng-transclude></div>' +
                        '<a ng-click="hi();">hi</a>' +
            '</div>',
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NNDhX/1/

Comment: Nice alternative, but overwriting scope's attr property seems like a hack.  I can imagine it might get you into trouble (especially if you're coming behind someone who did it).  Seems like it might be better to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Controller function inside a directive must be called within the transcluded block. Using the controller method inside the template of the directive make your directive depends on controller and is a undesirable design by its depedencies (directive-outer controller).

In your sample traslate the `<a>` piece of code to the transcluded block. It made your directive more isolated and solved the problem:

```
 <div class="zippy" zippy-title="Details: {{title}}...">
  {{text}}
  <a ng-click="hi();">hi</a>
</div>
```