# Cannot get '&' prefix working when defining isolated scope in basic angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm boning up on Angular directives and having trouble with the isolated scope. I'm making a VERY basic directive/controller and simply trying to throw an alert on an ng-click from within a directive by setting a scope attribute to the '&' prefix. I've been staring at this for 45 minutes now and can't see what I'm doing wrong, but nothing is happening when clicking the button (the other 2 prefixes are working though). Here is the code for the directive/controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('mePracticing')
        .directive('practiceDirective', practiceDirective);

    function practiceDirective() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                movie: '=',
                rating: '@',
                display: '&'
            },
            template: '<div>Movie: {{movie}}</div>' +
                "Enter a movie: <input type ='text' ng-model='movie'>" +
                "<div>Rating: {{rating}}</div>" +
                "<div><button ng-click='displayMovie(movie)'>CLICK ME</button></div>"
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();


(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('mePracticing')
        .controller('practiceController', practiceController);

    function practiceController($scope) {
        $scope.movie = 'The Big Lebowski';
        $scope.rating = 1000101010;
        $scope.displayMovie = function(movie) {
            alert("Movie :" + movie);
        }
    }
})();
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Directive Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="mePracticing">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>

    <div ng-controller="practiceController">
        <practice-directive movie="movie" display="display(movie)" rating="{{rating}}"></practice-directive>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="myDirective.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The app.js is just one line where I create my module:

```
angular.module('mePracticing', []);
```

If anyone can give me any tips on why that '&' isn't working I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

EDIT: I made a JSFiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/hozxz5n4/

Answer (score 2):

It occurs because when you are using the directive there is not a function called "display", you need to pass the declared function:

```
<practice-directive movie="movie" display="displayMovie(movie)" rating="{{rating}}"></practice-directive>
```

and finally in the directive just call display prop function:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('mePracticing')
    .directive('practiceDirective', practiceDirective);

  function practiceDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        movie: '=',
        rating: '@',
        display: '&'
      },
      template: '<div>Movie: {{movie}}</div>' +
        "Enter a movie: <input type ='text' ng-model='movie'>" +
        "<div>Rating: {{rating}}</div>" +
        "<div><button ng-click='display()'>CLICK ME</button></div>"
    };
    return directive;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Ahhh, I think I get it. When I declare the display=displayMovie(movie) attribute, that function gets passed from the controller to my directive as a function just called display, and inside the directive I just need to call display? Either way, this worked and thank you!

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Shouldn't the directive template have `display({movie: movie})`?

Answer (score 1):

The directive has its own isolated scope, so your `displayMovie()` function introduced in the `practiceController` never get's called. Move the function to your directive like so:

```js
function practiceDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        movie: '=',
        rating: '@',
        display: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.displayMovie = function(movie) {
                alert("Movie :" + movie);
        }
      },
      template: '<div>Movie: {{movie}}</div>' +
        "Enter a movie: <input type ='text' ng-model='movie'>" +
        "<div>Rating: {{rating}}</div>" +
        "<div><button ng-click='displayMovie(movie)'>CLICK ME</button></div>"
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hozxz5n4/1/

Also take a look at [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257066/5707534).